# SymmetricDS replication configuration for different schemas PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, schema, database-replication, symmetricds

I want to replicate other schemas rather than the public schema. I have configured the sym_trigger table for the different schema but it doesn't work cause there were no sym_* tables in that particular schema. Is there any way to configure the xxxx.properties file or just use this command

```
alter user {user name} set search_path to {schema name};
```

and configure the sym_* tables just like public schemas?

Answer (score 2):

The SymmetricDS tables will reside in the schema that is the default schema when you log in. If you want to access non-SymmetricDS tables in different schemas, you need to specify the source_schema_name in sym_trigger.

Comment: yes, I have tried and that works. But I have to set search_path for different schemas before specifying the source_schema_name in sym_trigger.

Comment: In sym_router, make sure that your router's use_source_catalog_schema column is set to 1.

Comment: I have successfully completed replication for for different sachems. you have grant usage on sachems for replication.